# Can i disable tabBarBadge on click of tab screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have used Tab.Navigator to display 4 bottom navigation icons, one of which is Notification Icon. I want to disable the `tabBarBadge` option when i click on it. How to do it?

Here is the code I used

```
 <Tab.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        component={Notifications}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) =>
            focused ? (
              <Notification_icon  />
            ) : (
              <Notification_icon_inactive />
            ),
          tabBarBadge: 2,
        }}
      />
```

Comment: You can simply use the state for these cases like for enable you can set true otherwise set it as false

Comment: tabBarBadge isnt boolean prop. It is either string or number

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I think it can't be hidden

Comment: To display badge provide either string or number in state. For hiding set your state to null.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this using `NavigationContainer`'s ref and controlling the visibility of the badges through some state variable. Listen for `state` event on the ref. In the handler of this event you get the name of the current route using `ref.current?.getCurrentRoute()?.name`. If this name is equal to the `Notifications` screen name then you set `notificationBadgeVisible` to false thus hiding the badges. Check the following code.

```
const App = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef<NavigationContainerRef>(null);

  const [notificationBadgeVisible, setNotificationBadgeVisible] = React.useState(true);

  const navigationStateChangeHandler = () => {
    if (ref.current?.getCurrentRoute()?.name === 'Notifications') {
      setNotificationBadgeVisible(false);
    }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current?.addListener('state', navigationStateChangeHandler);
    return () => { ref.current?.removeListener('state', navigationStateChangeHandler); }
  });

  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={ref}>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Notifications"
          component={Notifications}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) =>
              focused ? (
                <Notification_icon />
              ) : (
                <Notification_icon_inactive />
              ),
            tabBarBadge: (notificationBadgeVisible ? 2 : undefined)
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you @Fahad Farooq. I will try this and let you know if it worked.